# Durable Functions frequently stop or duplicate activities and/or orchestrations

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

We are running Azure Functions in a Consumption Plan using Durable Functions. We have Orchestrations that are started via Blob Triggers. These orchestrations will typically do the following activities:

1. Parse file
2. Make database calls for computations/linking of data
3. Insert data

   - On data insert, depending on how much data we're inserting, we'll chunk the insert process to X amount of records until we've completed inserting all records. This helps with timeout issues in some scenarios.

Our orchestration has semi-frequent issues (about twice weekly on average) where it will start inserting those chunks of data, but it won't fully complete.

**Scenario**: We received a file that we will break into 5 chunks to insert.

The process will complete steps 1 and 2. On step 3, it will insert **2 chunks**, hang for some time (I've seen anywhere from 10 seconds to 5 minutes), and then starts from the beginning and inserts all the data (**chunks 1 - 5**). As a result, **chunks 1 and 2 are duplicated** and the rest are new.

In total, inserting all chunks may take up to a minute and a half to complete on a regular run with no issues. When this issue occurs, I typically see this in the trace logs:

"**Initializing Warmup Extension**"

I imagine this may have to do with Scaling-Out/In, but I find it's a pretty huge flaw for this process to forget where it left off and to start from the beginning of an activity. Is there something we're not accommodating for here or is there a better approach to work this problem? Thank you in advance!

Comment: is an insert timing out? Do you use BlobClientOptions to control MaxRetries? Are you inserting from an Activity function or the orchestrator function itself?

Comment: No, the insert isn't timing out. We do not use BlobClientOptions to control MaxRetries. We actually have both scenarios for different jobs. One inserts from the activity function, the other is from the orchestrator function itself. Both scenarios have led to this same problem. Thank you and let me know if you have any more questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two problems with your solution, first is the use of consumption plan with durable function. You can have warm up long wait times and during the scale you can be switched to a different host.

The second is about the blob triggers, they are not too reliable. I recommend moving from the consumption plan to different plan and set the number of instances and see if this remediate the problem.

In the future consider moving away from blob triggers to a queue.